# Have a view cover entire screen except tab

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, subview

I am currently trying to create a temporary view that covers the entire window of my app (except the tab bar) while the background threads loads the content. The way I am doing this is the following

```
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
 let v = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
 window.addSubview(v)
```

However, this creates a view that covers the tab bar. Is there a way to have a view cover the entire screen except the tab bar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are in a view controller where there is a tab bar (i.e. inside a UITabBarController interface), the top of the tab bar is the bottom of the safe area, so instead of setting the frame to `window.bounds`, adjust the height of the frame in accordance with where the bottom of the safe area insets are.